# Convergence of the sequence $na_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Suppose $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers, and the sum

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k $$

converges, with the limit $\lim_{n} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1 $ (*).

The question is:
Is it always true that $\lim_{n} na_n = 0$ ?

We have seen that the statement is true when the sequence is decreasing, but does it still hold under condition (*)? Or are there any counter-examples? Waiting for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at a "bump" with $N b_N = 1$ and $|b_n/b_{n+1}-1| \le \epsilon$: say $b_n = (1+\epsilon)^{-|n-N|}/N$.  This has a sum of about $2/(N\epsilon)$. So we should be OK to take a sum of these bumps with $N$ going to $\infty$ faster than $1/\epsilon$.
Thus this ought to do it:

$$ a_n = \sum_{k=1}^\infty 3^{-k} (1+2^{-k})^{-\left| n - 3^k\right|}$$

Answer (score 0):

Idea for constructing a counter-example:

- start with a "barely convergent" series like the one given by $a_n=\frac{1}{n\log^2(n+1)}$
- for any $n$ which is a power of $2$, re-define $a_n$ as $\frac{1}{n}$ (this does not affect convergence but leads to $\limsup na_n=1$)
- re-define $a_m$ if $m$ is suitably close to a power of $2$, in such a way that $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1$.

Since $n=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)$, given $a_{2^p}=\frac{1}{2^p}$ we just need to tweak the values of $a_m$ for $|m-2^p|\leq 2p$.